# Getting random contacts from org

Tags: apex, method-invocation

I'm trying to get a 'n' number of random contacts from my org.
When I try executing the below mentioned code, i couldn't see anything in the debug section of the output screen

Can you guys please suggest here?

```
public class RandomCheck {

  list<Contact> rancon = new list<contact>();

    public list<contact> randomdisplay(integer datacount){
        integer total = [select count() from contact];
        rancon = [select name, email, phone from contact];

        list<integer> rannum = new list<integer>();
        for(integer i=0; i<datacount; i++){
            integer j= math.round(math.random()*total);
            rannum.add(j);
        }

        list<contact> showcon = new list<contact>();
        for(integer a=0; a<rannum.size(); a++){
           showcon.add(rancon.get(a));
        }      
        return showcon; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want achieve from the above code?

Comment: I have been working with the Math functions. So I thought of trying this one

Answer (score 2):

You should get the value from list **Rannum**

```
for(integer a=0; a<rannum.size(); a++){
    showcon.add(rancon.get(a));
}  

**Replace With**

for(integer a: rannum ){
       showcon.add(rancon.get(a));
} 



public class RandomCheck {

  list<Contact> rancon = new list<contact>();

    public list<contact> randomdisplay(integer datacount){
        integer total = [select count() from contact];
        rancon = [select name, email, phone from contact];

        list<integer> rannum = new list<integer>();
        for(integer i=0; i<datacount; i++){
            integer j= math.round(math.random()*total);
            rannum.add(j);
        }

        list<contact> showcon = new list<contact>();
        for(integer a: rannum ){
           showcon.add(rancon.get(a));
        }      
        return showcon; 
    }
}
```

**Update code.**

Best thing in below code is you never have duplicated contacts here. Just copy below code in anonymous windows and execute. make sure you have minimum  5 contacts.

```
public class RandomCheck {        
          list<Contact> rancon = new list<contact>();        
            public list<contact> randomdisplay(integer datacount){
                list<contact> showcon = new list<contact>();
                set<integer> rannum = new set<integer>();  // using set can element duplicate random number 
                integer total = [select count() from contact];
                rancon = [select name, email, phone from contact];        

                for(integer i=0; rannum.size()<datacount; i++){
                    integer j= math.round(math.random()*total);
                    rannum.add(j);
                }


                for(integer a: rannum )
                   showcon.add(rancon.get(a));

                system.debug('contact' + showcon);
                return showcon; 
            }
        }

 RandomCheck rc=new RandomCheck();
 rc.randomdisplay(5);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Nithesh. But still facing the same problem

Comment: I used: RandomCheck rc = new RandomCheck();
rc.randomdisplay(5);

Comment: @ArunKumar find the updated code.

Comment: Thank you @Nithesh... This worked. And I think it's because of the for loop near the end

Comment: @ArunKumar Your welcome. If your satisfied with answer please mark as best answer .